# how to output a pointer via MessageBox?

Tags: c++, winapi, pointers, assembly, messagebox

i have this code:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void getName(void)
{
    char buf[20];
    int slotNumber = 1;

    DWORD tempdw;
    DWORD hStorm_LOBBYPTR;
    hStorm_LOBBYPTR = (DWORD)GetModuleHandleW(L"Storm.dll") + 0x1000 + 0x40000 + 0x8000;


   __asm
    {
     PUSHAD
     MOV        EAX, DWORD PTR DS:[hStorm_LOBBYPTR]
     TEST       EAX, EAX
     JE         nick_false
     MOV        ECX, DWORD PTR DS:[EAX+0xC464]
     TEST       ECX, ECX
     JE         nick_false
     MOV        EAX, DWORD PTR DS:[ECX+0x170+0xB0]
     TEST       EAX, EAX
     JE         nick_false
     MOV        EDX, slotNumber
     MOV        ECX, DWORD PTR DS:[EAX+EDX*4]
     MOV        EAX, DWORD PTR DS:[ECX+0x1A0]
     MOV        ECX, DWORD PTR DS:[EAX+0x1E4]
     MOV        EAX, DWORD PTR DS:[ECX+0x1E4]
     MOV        ECX, DWORD PTR DS:[EAX+0x1E8]
     MOV        tempdw, ECX
     POPAD
     JMP        nick_true

nick_false:
     XOR        EAX, EAX
     MOV        tempdw, EAX
     POPAD
    }

    sprintf(buf,"%d", tempdw);
    MessageBox(0, buf, "Dll Injector", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
```

**`tempdw`** is a pointer, but when I try to look at it,
I have this kind of garbage in MessageBox: 
[image: screenshot pointer messagebox]

What should I do?

Comment: For starters, use `MessageBoxA` to be sure you're using the ASCII version.  Also, you'd usually use `%0p` as the format specifier for a pointer.

Comment: You say `tempdw` is a pointer - you should start by declaring it as such.

Comment: AFAIK, pointers should be formatted with "%x".

Comment: It looks like a non-null-terminated string, which means the call to sprintf failed for some reason.  Not knowing assembly, I can't imagine  how that could fail though.

Comment: MessageA doesn't help, declaring it as a pointer makes no difference.

Comment: Check the actual assembly from the debugger.

Comment: @Ben Since it takes `"Dll Injector"` fine I think we can be sure it's `MessageBoxA`. Clearly sprintf is not succeeding.

Comment: Could be that the `MOV tempdw,...` stuff doesn't work, since you fiddle with the stack pointer.

Comment: @jpalecek more details, please

Comment: @Jugo What happened when you tried my suggestion of removing the assembly?

Comment: Post the disassembled machine code (you can get it in the debugger, break on this function, show disassembler window).

Comment: @David Heffernan yes, I did. So the problem is wrong assembly code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that your assembly stomps over something (possibly a register) which means that the `sprintf` fails and the buffer just contains random stack noise.

Check this out by removing the assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Look up the "%p" print specifier in `printf`:

```
char temp_buffer[64];
char * p_temp_buffer = temp_buffer; // A pointer to display.
//...
sprintf(temp_buffer, "%p", (void *) p_temp_buffer);
MessageBox(0, temp_buffer, "Pointer value", MB_OK);
```

Comment: That may well be so but it could not explain the behaviour reported in the question.

Comment: The OP's question is how to display a pointer in a message box; which is what I answered.  I tend not to answer unexplained behavior questions.

Comment: But in this case, the unexplained behaviour is what Jugo is stuck on.